# Compare next item in loop, concatenate string and keep list items

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I have below `defaultdict(list)` called `cols`:

```py
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
{1: [{'text': 'Page',
       'top': Decimal('83.640')
    },{'text': '1,',
       'top': Decimal('83.640')
    },{'text': 'col',
       'top': Decimal('98.040')
    },{'text': '1.',
       'top': Decimal('98.040')
    }],
2: [{'text': 'Page',
    'top': Decimal('112.920')
    },{'text': '1,',
    'top': Decimal('112.920')
    },{'text': 'col',
    'top': Decimal('132.020')
    },{'text': '2.',
    'top': Decimal('132.020')
    }],
3: [{'text': 'Page',
    'top': Decimal('127.560')
    },{'text': '1,',
    'top': Decimal('127.560')
    },{'text': 'col',
    'top': Decimal('167.060')
    },{'text': '3',
    'top': Decimal('167.060')
}]})
```

That I would like to transform, so that for each `col` (1, 2 and 3) in the `defaultdict(list)`, I'd concatenate the `text` string, if the `top` value is equal to (or within a tolerance) level for the next `text` string in the list.

If not, I want to add what represents "a new line".

So, for example for the above list:

```
[0]:
Page 1,
Col 1.
[1]:
Page 1,
Col 2.
[2]:
Page 1,
Col 3.
```

This is my code so far:

```py
current_row = [list(cols.values())[0][0], ] #The first word.
row_list = [current_row,]
for col in cols.values():
    for i, word in enumerate(col):
        prevWord = col[i - 1]
        if i > 0:  # skip first word
            if abs(prevWord['bottom'] - word['bottom']) <= float(10): #10 is the tolerance level.
                #distance is small, use same row 
                current_row.append(word)
            else:
                # distance is big, create new row
                current_row = [word, ]
                row_list.append(current_row)
```

However, that just seems to just add a new list of all the elements (same as my original one, without the 1,2,3 keys).

## Expected output:

```py
{
    [{'text': 'Page 1,',
      'top': Decimal('83.640')
    },{'text': 'col 1.',
       'top': Decimal('98.040')
    }],
    [{'text': 'Page 1,',
      'top': Decimal('112.920')
    },{'text': 'col 2.',
       'top': Decimal('132.020')
    }],
    [{'text': 'Page 1,',
       'top': Decimal('127.560')
    },{'text': 'col 3.',
       'top': Decimal('167.060')
    }]
}
```

As you can see in above, the `text` has been concatenated if the `top` value is within the tolerance level and the `top` value is kept for the item.

Comment: I deleted my answer, because I didn't notice the tolerance. You already have a good procedure, you just need to do it. Try writing a helper function just for joining the words on one page, and that will help you debug. Use good variable names -- you currently have current_row referring to one word inside a row, at the top level (when you should be iterating pages). Don't confuse yourself on pages vs columns vs rows -- instead handle each inside their own function.

Comment: Thanks Kenny! Using Brandonwangs approach below is also solving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that when difference is within the tolerance level, you don't concatenate the strings; you just make a new item. Try this code:

```py
row_list = []
for col in cols.values():
    current_row = [col[0]]
    for i, word in enumerate(col):
        prevWord = col[i - 1]
        if i > 0:  # skip first word
            if abs(prevWord['top'] - word['top']) <= float(10): #10 is the tolerance level.
                #distance is small, use same row
                current_row[-1]['text'] += " " + word['text']
            else:
                # distance is big, create new row
                current_row.append(word) 
    row_list.append(current_row)
    current_row = []

print(row_list)
```